# Can't define rank in Tucker decomposition as equal to original dimension

Tags: python, tensorly

I'm trying to apply Tucker decomposition to a tensor `T` of shape `(500, 500, 3, 28)` with Tensorly's `tucker` and I can't define ranks where the rank is equal to the original dimension, for example:

I can do:

```
from tensorly.decomposition import tucker
tucker(T, [2, 2, 2, 27])
```

But when i change 27 to 28:

```
tucker(T, [2, 2, 2, 28])
```

The program hangs. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

If the rank is equal to the original size, then sparse SVD cannot be applied and a full (computationally heavy) SVD is required on the unfolding. By setting `init='random'` you bypass the SVD, which is why it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

What worked was to set `init='random'` in the `tucker` call.

Don't know exactly why though, but it worked.